# Problema al hacer click en un checkbox PHP js jquery html5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Buenas compañeros tengo un problema al hacer click en un checkbox, tengo guardado en la base de datos como 29 registros y al momento de hacer click solo funciona con el 1er registro en mi base de datos esta personalizado con 0 y 1, 0 seria cuando no esta checkeado y 1 cuando esta checkeado el problema tb es que solo esta reconociendo el primer ID por mas que haga click en los demas ID, aqui el codigo.

codigo php con lo principal

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fupForm" autocomplete="off" name="myForm" method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" id="idlv" name="idlv"  value="<?php echo $idlv; ?>">

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="venta" name="venta" class="check" <?php if ($venta==1) { ?> checked <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $idlv; ?>" />venta</label>


    <label><input type="checkbox" id="confiteria" name="confiteria" class="check" <?php if ($confiteria==1) { ?>checked <?php }  ?>  />Confiteria</label>

</form>
```

Codigo javascript con la funcionalidad

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: 'pruebachekin.php',

            data: new FormData(this),

            contentType: false,

            cache: false,

            processData: false,

            success: function(msg){

                $('.statusMsg').html('');

                if(msg == 'ok'){

                    $('#fupForm')[0].reset();

                    window.location.reload();

                }else{

                    console.log(msg);

                }

            }

        });     

    });

        $(".check").change(function(){
            $("#fupForm").submit();
        });
});
```

aqui el codigo ajax pero solo me devuelve el id en 1 por mas que haga click en otros id's

```
$venta = 0;

$confiteria = 0;

$idlv       = $_POST['idlv'];

if(!empty($_REQUEST['idlv']))

{

if(!empty($_POST['venta']))

{

$venta = ($_POST['venta']);

if ($venta='on')

{
     $venta=1;
   }

}

if(!empty($_POST['confiteria']))

{

$confiteria = ($_POST['confiteria']);

if ($confiteria='on'){

       $confiteria=1;

    }

 } 

  $queryUpd = mysqli_query($conection, "UPDATE lista_ventas SET venta = '$venta', confiteria = '$confiteria' WHERE idlv = $idlv ");

mysqli_close($conection);

 if($queryUpd){

    $code = '1';

    $msg = "Venta Actualizada.";

 }else{

    $code = '2';

    $msg = "Error.";

  }
    $arrData = array ('cod' => $code, 'msg' => $msg, 'venta' => $venta, 'confiteria' => $confiteria, 'idlv' => $idlv );

   echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   exit;

  }
```

Comment: Pon el código completo. Parece que faltan partes.

Comment: eso es lo mas principal

Answer (score 1):

En el código hay algunos errores:

```
if ($venta='on'){
     $venta=1;
   }
```

Debería ser  doble == (en confitería igual):

```
if ($venta=='on'){
     $venta=1;
   }
```

En ...

```
$venta = ($_POST['venta']);
```

Mejor sin paréntesis ...

```
$venta = $_POST['venta'];
```

Y donde creo que se poducia el error era en ...

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="venta" name="venta" class="check" <?php if ($venta==1) { ?> checked <?php } ?> value="<?php echo $idlv; ?>" />venta</label>
```

Le sobra el value. Así...

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="venta" name="venta" class="check" <?php if ($venta==1) { ?> checked <?php } ?> />venta</label>
```

Ya que no se recibía bien el valor de "venta".

Con estos cambios a mi me ha funcionado.

Si te sigue fallando. Después de la conexión pon ...

```
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo  "Falló la conexión";
        exit();
    }
```

Para comprobar que la conexión es correcta.

*Me imagino que tienes el "mysqli_connect" en el código original.*

---

Código completo funcionando:

Pagina **chekin.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: 'pruebachekin.php',

            data: new FormData(this),

            contentType: false,

            cache: false,

            processData: false,

            success: function(msg){

                $('.statusMsg').html('');

                if(msg == 'ok'){

                    $('#fupForm')[0].reset();

                    window.location.reload();

                }else{

                    console.log(msg);

                }

            }

        });

    });

        $(".check").change(function(){
            $("#fupForm").submit();
        });
});


</script>




<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fupForm" autocomplete="off" name="myForm" method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" id="idlv" name="idlv"  value="<?php echo $idlv; ?>">

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="venta" name="venta" class="check" <?php if ($venta==1) { ?> checked <?php } ?> />venta</label>


    <label><input type="checkbox" id="confiteria" name="confiteria" class="check" <?php if ($confiteria==1) { ?>checked <?php }  ?>  />Confiteria</label>

</form>
```

Página ajax **pruebachekin.php**

```
<?php

$venta = 0;

$confiteria = 0;

$idlv       = $_POST['idlv'];

$arrData = $_POST;




if(!empty($_REQUEST['idlv'])){

      if(!empty($_POST['venta'])){

      $venta = $_POST['venta'];

      if ($venta=='on'){
           $venta=1;
         }

      }

      if(!empty($_POST['confiteria'])){

      $confiteria = $_POST['confiteria'];

      if ($confiteria=='on'){

             $confiteria=1;

          }

       }
$conection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "NAME_USER", "PASS", "NAME_BBDD");
        $queryUpd = mysqli_query($conection, "UPDATE lista_ventas SET venta = '$venta', confiteria = '$confiteria' WHERE idlv = $idlv ");


        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo  "Falló la conexión";
            exit();
        }

      mysqli_close($conection);

       if($queryUpd){

          $code = '1';

          $msg = "Venta Actualizada.";

       }else{

          $code = '2';

          $msg = "Error.";

        }
          $arrData = array ('cod' => $code, 'msg' => $msg, 'venta' => $venta, 'confiteria' => $confiteria, 'idlv' => $idlv );

         echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

   exit;

  }
 ?>
```

Cambia estos datos por los tuyos de conexión ala BBDD:

> $conection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "NAME_USER", "PASS",
>   "NAME_BBDD");

Comment: Te comento que hice los cambios, pero igual sigo con el mismo error, lo raro es que solo le pasa el idlv 1 porque los demas campos que tengo no los esta tomando encuenta

Comment: Me devuelve esto, solo actualiza el idlv 1 por mas que haga click en los demas
{"cod":"1","msg":"Venta Actualizada.","venta":0,"confiteria":0,"idlv":"1"}

Comment: Repasa los cambios ya que a mi me sale en la consola correctamente así como en la base de datos.

Comment: He colgado el código funcionando completo. Cambia datos en consola y actualiza BBDD

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la Gran ayuda!!!!!